# More than 60000 chars gives string literal too long error on Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle 11g, I can't insert a string length larger 500000. I was given a error:

> ORA-01704: string literal too long.

The following code:

```
INSERT INTO administrative_hierachy_info VALUES('POLYGON ((107.720873283009 20.1180251073274, 107.721121071914 20.1180766955566, 107.721326861495 20.118147253042, 107.721528969524 20.1181872719219, 107.721692113556 20.1182339392041, 107.721849284091 20.118305337202, 107.722039254246 20.1183948201565, 107.722156919108 20.1184360524003, 107.722255108114 20.1184837225196, 107.72233976418 20.1184947791218, 107.722463912431 20.1185296836439, 107.722548258944 20.118528380499, 107.722743978319 20.118574633691, 107.722933425506 20.1186393948294, 107.723200808614 20.1186968142623, 107.723579692911 20.1188201983378, 107.72389740149 20.1189752126109, 107.724027951932 20.1190101072387, 107.724191407008 20.1190691316393, 107.724374253335 20.1191278560701, 107.724728106417 20.1193009015981, 107.725048318666 20.1194128250698, 107.725238396412 20.1195083493996, 107.725376734943 20.1196231752292, 107.725547540698 20.1197313616554, 107.725659351467 20.1198095946015, 107.725744763798 20.1198697343565, 107.725791726884 20.1199551976524, 107.725838785548 20.1200406594514, 107.725892467971 20.1201444299803, 107.725926333659 20.1202239587683, 107.725960612516 20.1203218021205, 107.726025532741 20.1205115884954, 107.726060038537 20.1206280200204, 107.726074735233 20.1207261662938, 107.726123193095 20.1208977960805, 107.726178678728 20.1211000024608, 107.726233418124 20.1212591706043, 107.72625567945 20.1214188412551, 107.726317125979 20.1215900894583, 107.726359195247 20.1217679550384, 107.726440724826 20.1221605489221, 107.726461717317 20.1222525508679, 107.726489728297 20.1223690827259, 107.726524979987 20.1225284620067, 107.726580360541 20.1227245326789, 107.726647655872 20.1228528209166, 107.726722202984 20.1230300934277, 107.72681635634 20.1232194268217, 107.726904108188 20.1234087689711, 107.726957579818 20.1235002680866, 107.726978443023 20.1235737704612, 107.727049755565 20.1237573201345, 107.727071044678 20.1238553641614, 107.727085852146 20.1239598260823, 107.727113341127 20.1240517273116, 107.72716072136 20.1241555947502, 107.727207802584 20.124253239481, 107.72730141258 20.1244056682323, 107.727395771198 20.1246012252781, 107.727482884277 20.1247536642208, 107.727569048613 20.124856931029, 107.72765541664 20.1249664219432, 107.727827936956 20.1251729523183, 107.727964945431 20.1253923967642, 107.728131835442 20.1256543377345, 107.728191791934 20.1257395085683, 107.728231944661 20.1258067553978, 107.728272189819 20.1258738202811, 107.728371547445 20.1259829290504, 107.728517566547 20.1261654109881, 107.728670282323 20.1263538358446, 107.728809481992 20.1265177411705, 107.728895743762 20.1266210056179, 107.729034401726 20.1267481870146, 107.72916049286 20.126900020952, 107.729322217494 20.1270513929187, 107.72950741446 20.1272393135764, 107.729639361318 20.1273541437643, 107.729810177011 20.1274622344286, 107.729908588528 20.1275222603413, 107.729993890715 20.1275702152571, 107.73015182327 20.1276847325079, 107.730270564419 20.1277874024564, 107.73043500435 20.1279079555946, 107.730586763072 20.1280410694866, 107.73067941614 20.128138096715, 107.730758754525 20.1282167386501, 107.730838737453 20.1283324635952, 107.730932258144 20.1284848911433, 107.731042434247 20.1286554715268, 107.731136479016 20.1288325292383, 107.731270459405 20.1290642010461, 107.731378685606 20.1293149539759, 107.731446413205 20.1294676908544, 107.731467301859 20.1295534660643, 107.73149499691 20.1296515000572, 107.731549745591 20.1298106654406, 107.73160981547 20.1299021505189, 107.73167127212 20.1300733956457, 107.731729484076 20.1302448715607, 107.731776678546 20.1303487400847, 107.731804159067 20.1304344129769, 107.731838565461 20.1305447071143, 107.731860395499 20.1306736074405, 107.731888317161 20.1307901391841, 107.731909621899 20.1308943189663, 107.731944241878 20.1310168838348, 107.731946916868 20.1311707196776, 107.731977072736 20.1314102283433, 107.731978571091 20.1314963944547, 107.731981031235 20.1316378692826, 107.731994721118 20.1318591319666, 107.732058653803 20.1321781689196, 107.732097341435 20.1325346002038, 107.732109506797 20.1328604869493, 107.732112395622 20.1330265935112, 107.732108146588 20.1331558983058, 107.732083874176 20.1332547382797, 107.732072915625 20.1333718730806, 107.732052413574 20.1334952027276, 107.732002596205 20.1336252144522, 107.731997598636 20.1337114813179, 107.731953837749 20.1338106236199, 107.731910396915 20.1339281720763, 107.731892287609 20.1340022780132, 107.731861198763 20.1340828125941, 107.731830121057 20.1341694840415, 107.731773260988 20.1342626924818, 107.731716708212 20.1343680799772, 107.731679027542 20.1344487167945, 107.731609698863 20.1345667570362, 107.731546342383 20.1346600661992, 107.731489802062 20.1347716807481, 107.731362647711 20.1349274401262, 107.731246213373 20.1351446743579, 107.73111396498 20.1353867019874, 107.730994281918 20.1356039864987, 107.730912171655 20.1357344086255, 107.730843067964 20.1358709465626, 107.730806230348 20.1359946197555, 107.7307631098 20.1361306644718, 107.730701581447 20.1363346826495, 107.730685076142 20.1365010900894, 107.730667832146 20.136630506211, 107.730647234911 20.1367539275389, 107.730642343384 20.1368463298281, 107.730643626542 20.1369201349742, 107.730638521682 20.1370002664805, 107.730622347475 20.1371912169649, 107.730585402835 20.1373087547601, 107.73055666426 20.1375245385216, 107.730507368522 20.1376791803715, 107.730458596474 20.1378584525269, 107.73044774192 20.1379816325152, 107.730405809895 20.1381915740737, 107.730373181337 20.1383705056292, 107.730348800755 20.1384632101403, 107.730295467873 20.1387594276272, 107.730234129372 20.1389634428143, 107.730184191489 20.1390811820626, 107.730140321677 20.1391741887739, 107.730092628261 20.139421041925, 107.730087843188 20.1395195796136, 107.73008966115 20.1396241519583, 107.730079943924 20.1399996551982, 107.730095291176 20.1401348834733, 107.730133762236 20.140478863959, 107.730144109747 20.1407002688821, 107.730152209371 20.1407923794563, 107.730199932301 20.1409209685806, 107.73026043012 20.1410368147249, 107.73033520892 20.1412265351413, 107.730362799611 20.1413184336515, 107.730404036058 20.141453170074, 107.730448818575 20.1415939885232, 107.730509640101 20.1417284211406, 107.730563763052 20.1418568205808, 107.730604560354 20.1419607882656, 107.730671343594 20.1420643528603, 107.73075058636 20.1421370389399, 107.730842927286 20.1422155685837, 107.73094816729 20.1422939883163, 107.73101408131 20.1423420621049, 107.731086197198 20.1423840831101, 107.73116490357 20.142425911584, 107.731270022813 20.1424918783845, 107.731401452983 20.1425761187497, 107.731559520869 20.1427029049432, 107.73171736274 20.1428111931103, 107.731947845302 20.1429861319656, 107.73217748233 ...');
```

Please help me resolve it!

Comment: This is not a C# issue. Please talk to Oracle customer service.

Comment: On the solution side, maybe you have too many digits. Could only 2 to 4 decimals be enough?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330 max string length is 4000. If you need more - use BLOB for example.

Comment: I don't know why you tagged this MySQL but 65535 (16-bits) is the maximum length of the `TEXT` field type in MySQL. Use `LONGTEXT` instead. I'm sure Oracle has it's own solution (apparently it's `CLOB`).

Answer (score 3):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) the maximum length of a SQL string constant is 4000 bytes in Oracle. If you enable [extended varchars](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321) it's 32k.

In PL/SQL [the maximum size](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/limits.htm#GUID-00966B4C-B9A5-47D4-94AA-54AEBCC07CE9__BABIHIJG) is always 32k.

You need to use bind variables if you want to pass a string literal that is longer.

In Java that would mean a [PreparedStatement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html) and in PL/SQL a [bind variable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#GUID-EF9233BB-9570-453D-96EB-E13F43B10596). Other programming languages have similar constructs.